# How to copy exception from modelstate to MudBlazor errors ValidationSummary

Tags: c#, blazor

In my backend api service, I am using fluent validation. If payload request fail validation, the endpoint returns this

[image]

How to copy exception from modelstate to MudBlazor error string array? This is my blazor code.

```
@page "/marketingeventcreate"

@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@using System.Text.RegularExpressions
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using OnlinePlatform.Support.Domain.Entities
@using OnlinePlatform.Support.Domain.Dtos

<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
<DataAnnotationsValidator/>
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="7">
        <MudCard>
            <MudCardContent>                
                <MudTextField Label="Event Name" HelperText=""
                              @bind-Value="model.Name" For="@(() => model.Name)"/>
                <MudTextField Label="Remark" Class="mt-3"
                              @bind-Value="model.Remark" For="@(() => model.Remark)"/>
                <MudTextField Label="Event Date" HelperText="" Class="mt-3" InputType="InputType.Date" 
                              Mask="@(new DateMask("dd.MM.yyyy"))" DateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" 
                              @bind-Value="model.EventDate" For="@(() => model.EventDate)" />
                <MudTextField Label="Venue" HelperText="" Class="mt-3" 
                              @bind-Value="model.Venue" For="@(() => model.Venue)" />
                <MudTextField Label="State" HelperText="" Class="mt-3" 
                              @bind-Value="model.State" For="@(() => model.State)" />
                <MudTextField Label="Start Time" HelperText="i.e. 2000" Class="mt-3"
                              @bind-Value="model.StartTime" For="@(() => model.StartTime)" />
                <MudTextField Label="End Time" HelperText="i.e. 2100" Class="mt-3"
                              @bind-Value="model.EndTime" For="@(() => model.EndTime)"  />
            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Submit</MudButton>
            </MudCardActions>
        </MudCard>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="5">
        <MudPaper Class="pa-4 mud-height-full">
            <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2">Validation Summary</MudText>
            @if (success)
            {
                <MudText Color="Color.Success">Success</MudText>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudText Color="@Color.Error">
                    <ValidationSummary />
                </MudText>
            }
        </MudPaper>
    </MudItem>    
</MudGrid>
</EditForm>
@code {
    MarketingEvent model = new MarketingEvent();
    bool success;
    string[] errors = { };

    private async Task OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
    {
        var mydate = new DateTime(model.EventDate.Year, model.EventDate.Month, model.EventDate.Day);

        var request = new CreateMarketingEventRequest(model.Name, model.Remark, mydate, model.Venue, 
            model.State, model.StartTime?.ToString(), model.EndTime?.ToString());


        try
        {
            var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/marketingevent", request);

            var serverCustomErrors = await response.Content
               .ReadFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();

            
            //for (int x = 0; x < serverCustomErrors.Count; x++)
            //{
            //    errors[x] = serverCustomErrors.ElementAt(x).Value.ToArray();
            //}
    
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                success = true;
                NavManager.NavigateTo("/");
                StateHasChanged();    
            }            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }            
    }    
}
```

In my Swagger, I tested it and the response is in `application/json` and not `application/problem+json`. Example,
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `JSON` error response - of which the picture only shows the `Errors` dictionary - follows the [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails) spec.

> A machine-readable format for specifying errors in HTTP API responses based on https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807.

You can define a similar class in your `Blazor` project (since you're most likely nog going to reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace).

```
public class ProblemDetails
{
    public IDictionary<string, IList<string>> Errors { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize you make the below call.
*Do make sure that the clientside `JSON` serializer settings match with the serverside ones to handle e.g. Pascal vs Camel casing.*

```
response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ProblemDetails>();
```

Such a `JSON` payload might look like the following.

```
{
    "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status":400,
    "traceId":"00-aeb74d510cffa1011e23109b55aae6ab-54a551c44656f2e4-00",
    "errors": 
    {
        "Name":
        [
            "Maximum of 200 characters allowed."
        ]
    }
}
```

---

To get these errors in the `<ValidationSummary />` or `<ValidationMessage For="..." />` tags , you'll going to have to transform your form into using an [`EditContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?#binding-a-form).

```
<EditForm EditContext="@MyEditContext">
```

That one is backed with e.g. a property

```
var MyEditContext  = new EditContex(model);
```

You then copy the errors in the `ProblemDetails` into the [`ValidationMessageStore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.validationmessagestore).

```
var messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(MyEditContext);

foreach (var error in problemDetails.Errors)
{
    messageStore.Add(MyEditContext.Field(error.Key), error.Value);
}

target.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
```

Reference: [ASP.NET Core Blazor forms and validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation#basic-validation)

Comment: I just tried `response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ProblemDetails>();` but `Errors` and `Title` is null

Comment: @Steve Make sure you have the clientside serializer configured in the same way as the serverside one, meaning if the server side applies Camel-casing, then you also need that clientside - same in case of Pascal-casing. That is not visible in the code and info you posted.

Comment: by the way, in my Swagger, I tested it and the response is in application/json and not application/problem+json.

Comment: @Steve That is a server-side Api concern.  I noticed you have an other question about this. It's better to handle that one separately since this one is a client-side/Blazor question.

Answer (score 1):

Since it was an internal error from the server we can create an customException which returns BadRequest and the error message

In your service

```
 if(responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
 {
  string errorContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  throw HttpException.HttpErrorMessage(errorContent);
 }
```

Then create a anotehr class for your custome exception

```
public class HttpException
{
    public static ApplicationException HttpErrorMessage(string customMessage)
    {
      return new ApplicationException(customMessage);
    }
}
```

Lastly in your code

```
try
  {

  }catch(Exception ex)
  {
   //Thsi the message that came from the server which have the internal error
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I need to find out how I can copy the error from modelstate to blazor ValidationSummary

Comment: https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/ maybe this can help you

Comment: actually i understand modelstate. Just now, I couldn't figure how I could map modelstate response to validationsummary in blazor editform